# Is it necessary to use key derivation when using Node's 'crypto' module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I need to implement symmetric encryption using a user's passphrase in a NodeJS application. When using [`crypto.createCipheriv()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options), do I need to perform some sort of key derivation on the passphrase to obtain a value for the `key` parameter, or is it sufficient to just pass the user's passphrase as-is and this is taken care of by the implementation?

Comment: Im not entirely understanding, what you want to do. you want to create a symmetric encryption using a passphrase of the user, and you will have it on the server side so will be able to use it as a seed in both sides? 
I'm not following what are you willing to do with these pieces. Are you willing to use a key separation technique or you just want to successfully and securely get a symmetric key?

Comment: `createCipheriv()` doesn't modify the user specified key, so yes, if you have a password you should use a KDF.

Comment: @DanielVega - no, this is an Electron app and encryption is for data being synchronized

Comment: @t.m.adam Thanks, that’s probably closest to what I’m looking for. Is my intuition that not stretching the passphrase is a Bad Idea correct? (My current thinking is to shove the passphrase and the user ID - both generated using nanoid that claims to produce sound character distributions from a CSPRNG - into Argon2; with only the ID ever existing outside the user’s device as cleartext, the derived key cached on it, the passphrase as close to never as is possible on the platform.)

Comment: Yes, never use a password as key. Argon2 is a very good  KDF, but it's not supported by `crypto` as far as I know. I'll post an answer using PBKDF2/scrypt if you're interested.

Comment: I’m using a separate argon2 lib for password hashing and verification anyway, so I can probably use that lib to spit out a buffer with the hashed passphrase input. Maybe, unless I decide to shove keygen into the rendered process to avoid IPC creating a bunch of copies of the plain passphrase. Then again the unencrypted data will be used on the user’s device so in case that’s compromised all bets are off anyway and jumping through hoops re: the passphrase is probably just security theater.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passwords should not be used as keys directly, but they can be used to produce a key with a KDF. That is because a key is expected to have a certain size and because passwords are weak - they use only a limited set of bytes and they usually contain words. This makes them vulnerable to both brute-force and dictionary attacks. KDFs not only produce long and uniform keys, but they also introduce a work factor which makes brute-force attacks impractical.

`createCipheriv()` does not modify the key contents or size. This is not mentioned in the documentation, but following the source code (from `createCipheriv`: [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3c277d7e92adf1464e41d27677fcdc05fec41a2b/lib/crypto.js#L111), to `Cipheriv`: [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3c277d7e92adf1464e41d27677fcdc05fec41a2b/lib/internal/crypto/cipher.js#L235), to `createCipherWithIV`: [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3c277d7e92adf1464e41d27677fcdc05fec41a2b/lib/internal/crypto/cipher.js#L119), to `prepareSecretKey`: [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3c277d7e92adf1464e41d27677fcdc05fec41a2b/lib/internal/crypto/keys.js#L272)) we see that the key is used as it is. So, the key is expected to have the right size and it should have enough complexity.

Crypto provides two password-based KDFs, scrypt and PBKDF2. It would be best to use scrypt because it is very expensive in terms of CPU and memory resources and it can be adjusted for parallel processing, while PBKDF2 only costs CPU resources. Both KDFs require a salt, which should be long and random.

Creating a key with [`scrypt`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback):

```
const keySize = 16; // for AES-128
const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const key = crypto.scryptSync('password', salt, keySize);
```

Creating a key with [`pbkdf2`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback):

```
const keySize = 16; // for AES-128
const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync('password', salt, 10000, keySize, 'sha256');
```

Where 'sha256' is the underlying hash and 10000 is the recommend minimum number of iterations, that determines the work factor. In scrypt the general work factor is an optional parameter with default value 16384 (2^14), and can be set in `options['cost']`, where we can also set the block size and parallelization. Those values can be increased quite a lot, depending on the OS; each operation should take about 100 ms.

Finally, Argon2 is considered to be a very good KDF and like scrypt it can be adjusted for CPU and memory consumption and parallel processing. Although Argon2 it is not available in `crypto`, it is provided by other Node.js packages.

Comment: Came up with another ***[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796837/cant-supply-some-returned-result-to-a-function-using-multiprocessing)*** @t.m.adam. Will be happy if you intervene. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty of breaking a cipher depends more on the used algorithm than the length of the password. (omitting brut-force attacks)

The key extension does not increase security, because you still have the same short password at the begining. For your safety, immediately assume that you had a break-in and application code was leaked. That is, all standard and custom algorithms are public.

And you will have to use the password extension anyway, because most of the algorithms require a secret with a specific length.

---

#### An earlier answer, a little off topic.

TL;DR: The best way is to process the password into a binary buffer (string).

The symmetric encryption is precisely based on the fact that having the secret you are able to perform the reverse operation. **Symetric** mean operations are reversible.

Your programming language, framework or library does not matter.

Some differences are at the stage of packaging the encrypted message. You can receive a raw message, or a beautifully formatted message, where you have added IV and content in base64.

You also have to process the key in the same way. But it's about coding `big endian` and `little endian` and character encoding eg: `utf-8`, `latin2`

`IV` is an additional protection that aims to generate different encrypted messages for the same incoming message and secret. But as it is written in the last paragraph of the section you are targeting:

> They do not have to be secret: IVs are typically just added to
>   ciphertext messages unencrypted.

In summary: you do not need to affect the encryption process itself, and you need to check what data the Electron needs.

For example my decrypt procedure (in node, data from PHP):

```
let crypto = {
  key: Buffer.from('secret in hex', 'hex'),
  cipher: 'aes-128-cbc',
  iv_size: 16
}
    let bData = Buffer.from(data.replace(/ /g,'+'), 'base64');
    let iv = bData.slice(0, crypto.iv_size);
    let text = bData.slice(crypto.iv_size);
    var decipher = crypt.createDecipheriv(crypto.cipher, crypto.key, iv);
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
    var decrypted = decipher.update(text,'hex','hex');
    decrypted += decipher.final('hex');
```

For PHP encrypt:

```php
    $data = mcrypt_encrypt($this->_cipher, $this->_key, $data, $this->_mode, $iv);

    // Use base64 encoding to convert to a string
    return base64_encode($iv.$data);

//where
array(
        'key'=> urldecode('secret in urlencode'),
        'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        'mode'   => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
       ),
```

As you can see, I had to find the encryption algorithms implemented on both platforms, and provide a way to provide an identical key on both platforms.

Comment: I’m not sure what this has to do with my question though? I (think I) know roughly how to roundtrip data through a cipher, I was asking if it’s fine from a security standpoint to use the passphrase directly as input to the cipher, or if I should stretch it with a KDF. Clearly either will “work” as in allow for encrypting then decrypting the data correctly for parties that know the passphrase and KDF if applicable; I’m concerned about whether not using a KDF in my code will make it easier for an attacker to decrypt the data.

Comment: i.e. I’m asking about how to correctly produce the “secret” in your example code, something that happens before everything you’re covering. As for my comment you say you’re reacting to, assuming you mean my answer to Daniel Vega, I just cleared up what seemed to be his assumption that when I say “NodeJS”, I mean a server-side application and that a server is storing a user’s passphrase, which would make using symmetric encryption with such a passphrase pointless to begin with. But I’m not doing that.