# Can't modify a function to work independently instead of depending on a returned result

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I've written a script in python making use of proxies while sending requests to some links in order to parse the product name from there. My current attempt does the job flawlessly. This function `parse_product()` is fully dependent on the returned result (proxy) in order to reuse the same proxy in the right way. I'm trying to modify `parse_product()` function in such a way so that the very function does not depend on a previous call to the same function in order to reuse a working proxy until invalid. To be clearer - I'm expecting the main function to be more like below. However, when it is done solving, I'll use multiprocessing to make the script run faster:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for url in linklist:
        parse_product(url)
```

and still, expect that the script will work as it is now.

I've tried with (working one):

```
import random
import requests
from random import choice
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

linklist = [
    'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00OI0RGGO', 
    'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKOPWA', 
    'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TH42HWE' 
]

proxyVault = ['103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632', '1.20.101.95:49001', '200.10.193.90:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128', '103.228.118.66:43002', '178.128.231.201:3128', '1.2.169.54:55312', '181.52.85.249:31487', '97.64.135.4:8080', '190.96.214.123:53251', '52.144.107.142:31923', '45.5.224.145:52035', '89.218.22.178:8080', '192.241.143.186:80', '113.53.29.218:38310', '36.78.131.182:39243']

def process_proxy(proxy):
    global proxyVault
    if not proxy:
        proxy_url = choice(proxyVault)
        proxy = {'https': f'http://{proxy_url}'}
    else:
        proxy_pattern = proxy.get("https").split("//")[-1]
        if proxy_pattern in proxyVault:
            proxyVault.remove(proxy_pattern)
        random.shuffle(proxyVault)
        proxy_url = choice(proxyVault)
        proxy = {'https': f'http://{proxy_url}'}
    return proxy


def parse_product(link,proxy):
    try:
        if not proxy:raise
        print("checking the proxy:",proxy)
        res = requests.get(link,proxies=proxy,timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html5lib")
        try:
            product_name = soup.select_one("#productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
        except Exception: product_name = ""

        return proxy, product_name

    except Exception:
        """the following line when hit produces new proxy and remove the bad one that passes through process_proxy(proxy)"""
        proxy_link = process_proxy(proxy)
        return parse_product(link,proxy_link)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxy = None
    for url in linklist:
        result = parse_product(url,proxy)
        proxy = result[0]
        print(result)
```

Note: `parse_product()` function returns a proxy and a product name. However, the proxy the function returns gets reused within the same function `parse_product()` until invalid.

By the way, proxies used within proxyVault are just placeholders.

Comment: I'm not that experienced with multithreading, but I don't know if this task can be parallelized, because the function requires as a parameter the result of a function that runs in parallel. You may have to change the logic of the script, so that the function doesn't depend on a previous call to the same function.

Comment: Well, I think the `parse_product()` function matches that criteria. There is a recursive call, but that shouldn't be a problem because the call comes from inside the function. The important thing is that the `proxy` parameter comes from a call to `process_proxy()`, not from a call to `parse_product()`, so `parse_product()` can be parallelized as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay, this is a little more complicated than I thought. I think you can't have `proxy` as a parameter, but you can make it a global, so that `process_proxy()` (sidenote: maybe you have to use a lock because `process_proxy()` modifies shared resources) doesn't return a value but modifies a global `proxy` variable. Still, the problem is that if a proxy is bad, all threads will request a new proxy via `process_proxy()`, so you will have 5 new proxies instead of one. ...

Comment: ... I can't think of an elegant way to solve this, but a possible solution is to keep track of the current proxy and check if it is the same as the global proxy, or if the global proxy has been changed by another thread, in which case you wouldn't call `process_proxy()` before you call `parse_product()` recursively.

Comment: Hi @t.m.adam, I've put a bounty to get any solution.

Comment: The method I proposed above should work, but I'm sure you'll get much better answers.

Comment: Your suggestion never fails but the problem is I highly doubt I can modify it myself to follow that. Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed that you've changed the main point of the question and removed the multithreading tag. I think you should make it clear that the function should be parallelizable. The `proxy` parameter only becomes an issue when the function runs in parallel. You should also consider that a bad proxy will cause multiple calls to `process_proxy()`, which I think is at least a bug.

Comment: Your proposed idea makes the design worse. Although `__main__` is simplified a bit, the function it calls now has to maintain hidden state somehow. The function has a stashed proxy somewhere, which it replaces with a good one if it goes bad.  The original solution is more functional. "I had to use a different proxy, and here it is; if you call me again, give me that one, if you want". The state management is then very simple and explicit: it consists of the  `proxy` local variable in the `__main__` loop. The state management is also thereby kept out of the `parse_product` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need multithreading support (your edits suggest you don't), you can make it work with the following minor changes. `proxyVault` keeps both the entire proxy pool, **and** the active proxy (the last one) after shuffling the list (your code had both `shuffle` and `choice`, but just one of them is enough). `pop()`-ing from the list changes the active proxy, until there are no more left.

```
import random
import requests
from random import choice
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

linklist = [
    'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00OI0RGGO',
    'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKOPWA',
    'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TH42HWE'
]

proxyVault = ['103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632', '1.20.101.95:49001', '200.10.193.90:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128', '103.228.118.66:43002', '178.128.231.201:3128', '1.2.169.54:55312', '181.52.85.249:31487', '97.64.135.4:8080', '190.96.214.123:53251', '52.144.107.142:31923', '45.5.224.145:52035', '89.218.22.178:8080', '192.241.143.186:80', '113.53.29.218:38310', '36.78.131.182:39243']
random.shuffle(proxyVault)


class NoMoreProxies(Exception):
    pass


def skip_proxy():
    global proxyVault
    if len(proxyVault) == 0:
        raise NoMoreProxies()
    proxyVault.pop()


def get_proxy():
    global proxyVault
    if len(proxyVault) == 0:
        raise NoMoreProxies()
    proxy_url = proxyVault[-1]
    proxy = {'https': f'http://{proxy_url}'}
    return proxy


def parse_product(link):
    try:
        proxy = get_proxy()
        print("checking the proxy:", proxy)
        res = requests.get(link, proxies=proxy, timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html5lib")
        try:
            product_name = soup.select_one("#productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
        except Exception:
            product_name = ""

        return product_name

    except Exception:
        """the following line when hit produces new proxy and remove the bad one that passes through process_proxy(proxy)"""
        skip_proxy()
        return parse_product(link)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for url in linklist:
        result = parse_product(url)
        print(result)
```

I would also suggest changing the last try/except clause to catch a `RequestException` instead of `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can put the proxy handling logic inside a class, and pass an instance to `parse_product()`. Then, `parse_product()` will invoke the necessary methods of the instance to get and/or reset the proxy. The class can look something like this:

```
class ProxyHandler:
    proxyVault = [
        "103.110.37.244:36022",
        "180.254.218.229:8080" # and so on
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Initialize proxy
        proxy_url = choice(self.proxyVault)
        self.proxy = {"https": f"http://{proxy_url}"}

    def get_proxy(self):
        return self.proxy

    def renew_proxy(self):
        # Remove current proxy from the vault
        proxy_pattern = self.proxy.get("https").split("//")[-1]
        if proxy_pattern in proxyVault:
            proxyVault.remove(proxy_pattern)

        # Set new proxy
        random.shuffle(proxyVault)
        proxy_url = choice(self.proxyVault)
        self.proxy = {"https": f"http://{proxy_url}"}
```

Then, `parse_product()` might look something like this:

```
def parse_product(link, proxy_handler):
    try:
        if not proxy_handler:
            raise
        proxy = proxy_handler.get_proxy()
        print("checking the proxy:", proxy)
        res = requests.get(link, proxies=proxy, timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html5lib")
        try:
            product_name = soup.select_one("#productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
        except Exception:
            product_name = ""

        return product_name

    except Exception:
        """the following line when hit produces new proxy and remove the bad one that passes through process_proxy(proxy)"""
        proxy_handler.renew_proxy()
        return parse_product(link, proxy_handler)
```

I think you can pass the same `ProxyHandler` instance to all threads and parallelize too.

Comment: You cannot pass the same ProxyHandler instance as you suggested to multiple threads, as the renew_proxy method is not thread-safe. Also making it thread-safe is not as trivial as just throwing in a lock, since you'll have threads renewing the proxy multiple times each time one proxy fails

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something crucial here (as it's pretty late), but it seems a simple problem which was extremely overcomplicated. It almost tends to be an *XY Problem*. I'm going to post some thoughts, questions (wanderings of mine), observations, suggestions:

- The end goal is that for each link, access it (**once** or as many times possible ? if it's the latter, it seems like a *DoS* attempt, so I'll assume it's the former :) ) using each of the proxies (when a proxy fails, move to next). If that works, get some product (which seems to be some kind of an electric motor) name
- Why the recursion? It's limited by the stack (in *Python* by [[Python 3.Docs]: sys.**getrecursionlimit**()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit))
- No need to declare variables as *global* if not assigning values to them (there are exceptions, but I don't think it's the case here)
- *process_proxy* (question variant) isn't behaving well when *proxyVault* gets empty
- `global proxy` (from the answer) is just ugly
- Why *random* instead of simply picking the next proxy from the list?
- *parse_product_info* (*parse_product*) behavior is not consistent, in some cases returns something, in others it doesn't
- Parallelization occurs only at target *URL* level. It can be improved a bit more (but more logic needs to be added to the code), if also working at proxy level

Below it's a simplified (and cleaner) version.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urls = [
    "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00OI0RGGO",
    "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKOPWA",
    "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TH42HWE",
    "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKNREM",
]

proxies = [
    "103.110.37.244:36022",
    "180.254.218.229:8080",
    "110.74.197.207:50632",
    "1.20.101.95:49001",
    "200.10.193.90:8080",
    "173.164.26.117:3128",
    "103.228.118.66:43002",
    "178.128.231.201:3128",
    "1.2.169.54:55312",
    "181.52.85.249:31487",
    "97.64.135.4:8080",
    "190.96.214.123:53251",
    "52.144.107.142:31923",
    "45.5.224.145:52035",
    "89.218.22.178:8080",
    "192.241.143.186:80",
    "113.53.29.218:38310",
    "36.78.131.182:39243"
]


def parse_product_info(link):  # Can also pass proxies as argument
    local_proxies = proxies[:]  # Make own copy of the global proxies (in case you want to shuffle them and not affect other parallel processing workers)
    #random.shuffle(local_proxies)  # Makes no difference, but if you really want to shuffle it, decomment this line
    for proxy in local_proxies:
        try:
            proxy_dict = {"https": f"http://{proxy}"}  # http or https?
            print(f"    Proxy to be used: {proxy_dict['https']}")
            response = requests.get(link, proxies=proxy_dict, timeout=5)
            if not response:
                print(f"    HTTP request returned {response.status_code} code")
                continue  # Move to next proxy
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html5lib")
            try:
                product_name = soup.select_one("#productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
                return product_name  # Information retrieved, return it.
            except Exception as e:  # Might want to use specific exceptions
                print(f"ERROR: {e}")
                # URL was accessible, but the info couldn't be parsed.
                # return, as probably it will be the same using any other proxies.
                return None  # Replace by `continue` if  you want to try the other proxies
        except Exception as e:
            #print(f"    {e}")
            continue  # Some exception occured, move to next proxy


def main():
    for url in urls:
        print(f"\nAttempting url: {url}...")
        product_name = parse_product_info(url)
        if product_name:
            print(f"{url} yielded product name:\n[{product_name}\\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output** (partial, as I didn't let it go through all proxies / *URL*s):

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058796837]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
>
> Attempting url: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00OI0RGGO...
>     Proxy to be used: http://103.110.37.244:36022
>     Proxy to be used: http://180.254.218.229:8080
>     Proxy to be used: http://110.74.197.207:50632
>     Proxy to be used: http://1.20.101.95:49001
>     Proxy to be used: http://200.10.193.90:8080
>     Proxy to be used: http://173.164.26.117:3128
>     ...
> ```